# won't add custom pin image

Tags: ios, swift

i'm trying to add a custom pin image however it keep showing that standard red pin instead of the image. what am i doing wrong?

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        reuseId = "Pin"
        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
         pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.image = UIImage(named: "pikachu.png")
        return pinView
}
```

Comment: I don't think you want to use MKPinAnnovationView then. You should use MKAnnotationView instead. Strange thing you doing with double dequeue and an init after also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this If you want to change Pin as image then you have to use `MKAnnotationView`

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {



    reuseId = "Pin"
    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKAnnotationView


    pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId) as? MKAnnotationView
    pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

    pinView?.image = UIImage(named: "pikachu.png")



    return pinView


}
```